# Matrix: Vertical Cell Organization in cp

Tags: matrix

I use Matrix with a Multi-language plugin (bieber.ltd).
Multi-language capabilities results in a plethora of fields especially within matrix.

So I wonder if its possible to stack cels vertically in the cp-panel:

```
| cell_title_de | cell_description_de |
| cell_title_en | cell_description_en |
```

instead of

```
| cell_title_de | cell_title_en | cell_description_de | cell_description_en |
```

Anybody knows something about this?

Comment: Wouldn't vertically stacked cells be 'rows'?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. The [Nolan Add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/nolan) does what I wanted. There is an option to stack the nolan field verticaly. Now it looks pretty :) And it even works within the multi-language environment.

Comment: Very cool solution.